# AngularJS : hide <td> without gap using ng-hide/ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have code looking like this :

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>                 <!-- td1 -->
      <td ng-show="var">how are</td> <!-- td2 -->
      <td ng-hide="var">you</td>     <!-- td3 -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

The td1 is correctly hidden, but when td2 is hidden it create an empty gap.
I'd like td2 to be fully replaced by td3.

Using only AngularJS and not jQuery would be cool.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by empty gap ? i can not reproduce it http://plnkr.co/edit/Dbw7VGmQu8s75cGEmhrG?p=preview

Comment: ng-hide set css to display:none. so there should be no gap. it is not set to  visibility: hidden. So your gap has a other reason. please provide your real code

Answer (score 4):

You should use `ng-if` instead of `ng-hide`. `ng-if` will actually remove the element from the DOM.

`ng-show`/`ng-hide` simply changes the `display` css property of your element.

For example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>               <!-- td1 -->
      <td ng-if="var">how are</td> <!-- td2 -->
      <td ng-if="!var">you</td>    <!-- td3 -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) if you use animations and want them to work like with `ng-show`/`ng-hide`.

Answer (score 0):

Use "ng-if" instead of "ng-show". For example:-

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>                       <!-- td1 -->
      <td ng-if="var==true">how are</td>   <!-- td2 -->
      <td ng-hide="var==false">you</td>    <!-- td3 -->
  </tr>
</table>
```